# Keeping/Storing a running total outside of function from inside a function

Tags: python

Hey i'm working on a small project for school and i need to keep a running tally outside of a function whilst re running the program inside the function for any number of times.I've tried different things but i cant get it to stop resetting the value of my tally any help would be appreciated.This is my code so far:

```
import sys
r = open("teacherfine.txt","r")

a = 0
b = 0


def f(enter):
    b = 0
    for line in r:
        if line.startswith(enter):
            c = line.split(",")
            print(c)
            print(c[1],"owes",c[2])
            global a
            a = a =+ float(c[2])
            d = input("Do you want to add another code?(yes/no)")
            if d == "yes":
                z = input("enter code")
                f(z)
            elif d != "yes":
                print("the total owed was",a)
                sys.exit()




z= input("enter code")
f(z)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're code is correct ? b is not used and `a = a =+ float(c[2])` seems suspicious. Try to explain more your problem and giving a toy example would be better. Like a list of string instead of your file `teacherfine.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

okay, not understanding what you are trying to ask. But looking at the code, the problem maybe that you have put `b = 0` twice, one outside and one inside the `def f(enter):` which may reset the value... if this is not the answer, please give more detail in what this code actually does, as I'm not exactly following, but I may be able to help you.

Comment: Looking back on my question i explained poorly my school project is to have someone enter a 3 digit code and that code should refer to a particular teacher in the file "teacherfine.txt" the file is formatted so that it looks like this, "001, Mr Jones, 2.20, ICT" i have to print out the details and then ask the user if they want to input another code the program should then stack the amount owed so at the end the total amount owed should be outputted.Ive got some of the way through but i still cant figure out how to get the overall amount owed working.